# How do I center my navigation bar so it will be placed in the middle at the top of my page?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I found this really awesome navigationbar template on the internet, but now I'm having troubles with positioning my navigation bar. I want the bar in the middle at the top of my screen. Everything I've tried thus far hasn't worked.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="Login.html">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 18px 25px 12px 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  content: "";
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover:after {
  background: #d7d7d7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an option for that built into your CSS

```
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

Just add the `align-center` class to your wrapping div.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
 #cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 18px 25px 12px 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  content: "";
  transition: all .2s ease;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover:after {
  background: #d7d7d7;
}
```

```html
<div id="cssmenu" class="align-center">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Login.html">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you check carefully you'll see there's a right alignment option too. The default is aligned left.

I suspect that this was in the documentation where you found the code.